# Formatear Listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

tengo la lista: lista = [1,2,3,4]
y quiero formatear mi lista para que sea asi :
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |

donde mi funcion recibe los parametros :

```
formatear_lista(lista, cantidad_espacios, cadena_inicial, cadena_separadora, cadena_final)

formatear_lista(lista, 5, '|', '|', '|')
```

alguna ayuda o indicaciones pls

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta? No vamos a hacer esa función por ti. Sobre las indicaciones, seguramente el método join de los str te sea util. Puedes aprender sobre ella en [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) o en [cualquier otra pagina de internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=join+python&oq=join+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l5j69i60l2.2530j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) para más detalles.

Comment: Yo usaría una cadena de formato, tipo `"{}{}{}".format(...)` y en `format` pondría como parámetros la cadena inicial, el resultado de un `join` con la cadena separadora y la cadena final. Eso como "ayuda o indicación" debería bastarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola buenas  habría varias maneras:

```
lista= [1,2,3,4] #lista dada

def formatear_lista(lista, cantidad_espacios, cadena_inicial, cadena_separadora, 
cadena_final):
    lista.append('')#añadimos un espacio a la lista
    for i in lista:#recorremos la lista
       k=cadena_inicial#creamos una variable que le damos el valor de cadena_inicial
       for j in range(cantidad_espacios):#recorremos el numero de espacios dados en los argumentos
          k=f'{cadena_separadora} {i} '#añadimos a la variable las separaciones del argumento junto con el recorrido de la lista en i
    
       print(k,end='')#imprimimos la variable seguida
```

Entrada:

```
formatear_lista(lista, 5, '|', '|', '|')
```

Out:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

también con el método join() y map():

```
lista= [1,2,3,4] 

def formatear_lista(lista, cantidad_espacios, cadena_inicial, cadena_separadora, cadena_final):
  lista =cadena_separadora.join(map(str, lista))
  lista+=cadena_final
  lista=cadena_inicial+lista
  print(lista)
```

Comment: En el bucle `cantidad_espacio` siempre obtienes el mismo resultado intenta: `k+=f"{cadena_separadora} {i} "; ` o simpremente omites el bucle y simpremente concatenas todo dentro de `print`: `print(f"{cadena_inicial} {cadena_separadora} {i}",end="");` y si quieres que la cantidad de espacio cuente haces esto: `print(cadena_inicial+(" "*cantidad_espacio)+cadena_separadora+str(i),end="");`

Comment: yeah!!! cierto, gracias Daniel

Comment: No se que opina el resto de la comunidad, pero para mi es importante que haya una explicación de lo que hace el código. De ese modo el OP y otros aprenden en lugar de solo solucionar el problema que tienen actualmente.

Comment: No digo que los comentarios estén mal, pero siempre prefiero explicarlo fuera del código. Es solo una sugerencia, no lo tomes a mal